# Getting "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later"

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm, php5, varnish

I have a vps running **Ubuntu+LEMP**+Varnish. Everything was fine untill I updated the server software.

Now I am getting "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later" on every pages. (Header response is 502)

I tried figure out. and here is what I got while updating.

The following is the difference beteen www.conf:

```
--- /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf       2013-10-22 14:30:39.000000000 +0000
+++ /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.dpkg-new      2014-06-20 00:40:35.000000000 +0000
@@ -30,7 +30,7 @@
 ;                            specific port;
 ;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
 ; Note: This value is mandatory.
-listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
+listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

 ; Set listen(2) backlog. A value of '-1' means unlimited.
 ; Default Value: 128 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
@@ -40,10 +40,10 @@
 ; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
 ; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
 ; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
-;                 mode is set to 0666
+;                 mode is set to 0660
 ;listen.owner = www-data
 ;listen.group = www-data
-;listen.mode = 0666
+;listen.mode = 0660
```

Here is the whole terminal activity when the server was upgraded:

```
login as: demouser
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Verification code:
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Tue Jun 17 08:48:07 2014 from 117.197.66.168
demouser@Titan:~$ varnishstat
demouser@Titan:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for demouser:
Hit http://apt-longview.linode.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://apt-longview.linode.com precise Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://apt-longview.linode.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://apt-longview.linode.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://apt-longview.linode.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://apt-longview.linode.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free i386 Packages
Ign http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free TranslationIndex
Hit http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise Release.gpg
Hit http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise Release
Ign http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise/varnish-4.0 i386 Packages
Ign http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise/varnish-4.0 TranslationIndex
Ign http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise/varnish-4.0 Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.varnish-cache.org precise/varnish-4.0 Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
demouser@Titan:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libssl-dev libssl-doc
  libssl1.0.0 libxml2 openssl php5-common php5-curl php5-fpm php5-gd
  php5-mysql
14 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libapt-pkg4.12 i386                                                                                         0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17 [942 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main apt i386 0.8.16~exp                                                                                        12ubuntu10.17 [1,105 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libssl-doc all 1.0.                                                                                        1-4ubuntu5.16 [1,033 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libssl-dev i386 1.0                                                                                        .1-4ubuntu5.16 [1,425 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libssl1.0.0 i386 1.                                                                                        0.1-4ubuntu5.16 [1,007 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libapt-inst1.4 i386                                                                                         0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17 [103 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libxml2 i386 2.7.8.                                                                                        dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.9 [662 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-mysql i386 5.3                                                                                        .10-1ubuntu3.12 [73.3 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-curl i386 5.3.                                                                                        10-1ubuntu3.12 [27.9 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-gd i386 5.3.1                                                                                        0-1ubuntu3.12 [37.5 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe php5-fpm i386                                                                                         5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12 [3,134 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-common i386 5                                                                                        .3.10-1ubuntu3.12 [163 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main apt-utils i386 0.8                                                                                        .16~exp12ubuntu10.17 [192 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main openssl i386 1.0.1                                                                                        -4ubuntu5.16 [519 kB]
Fetched 10.4 MB in 2s (3,871 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 35787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libapt-pkg4.12 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16 (using .../libapt-pk                                                                                        g4.12_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libapt-pkg4.12 ...
Setting up libapt-pkg4.12 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
(Reading database ... 35787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace apt 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16 (using .../apt_0.8.16~exp12ubun                                                                                        tu10.17_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement apt ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up apt (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17) ...
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"                                                                                         not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"                                                                                         not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubunt                                                                                        u.com>" not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu                                                                                        .com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
(Reading database ... 35787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libssl-doc 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.15 (using .../libssl-doc_1.0.1-4u                                                                                        buntu5.16_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libssl-doc ...
Preparing to replace libssl-dev 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.15 (using .../libssl-dev_1.0.1-4u                                                                                        buntu5.16_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libssl-dev ...
Preparing to replace libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.15 (using .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-                                                                                        4ubuntu5.16_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libssl1.0.0 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libssl1.0.0 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
(Reading database ... 35787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libapt-inst1.4 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16 (using .../libapt-in                                                                                        st1.4_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libapt-inst1.4 ...
Preparing to replace libxml2 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.8 (using .../libxml2_2.7.8.df                                                                                        sg-5.1ubuntu4.9_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libxml2 ...
Preparing to replace php5-mysql 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 (using .../php5-mysql_5.3.10-                                                                                        1ubuntu3.12_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-mysql ...
Preparing to replace php5-curl 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 (using .../php5-curl_5.3.10-1u                                                                                        buntu3.12_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-curl ...
Preparing to replace php5-gd 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 (using .../php5-gd_5.3.10-1ubunt                                                                                        u3.12_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-gd ...
Preparing to replace php5-fpm 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 (using .../php5-fpm_5.3.10-1ubu                                                                                        ntu3.12_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-fpm ...
Preparing to replace php5-common 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 (using .../php5-common_5.3.1                                                                                        0-1ubuntu3.12_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-common ...
Preparing to replace apt-utils 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.16 (using .../apt-utils_0.8.                                                                                        16~exp12ubuntu10.17_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement apt-utils ...
Preparing to replace openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.15 (using .../openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5                                                                                        .16_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement openssl ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libssl-doc (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16) ...
Setting up libssl-dev (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16) ...
Setting up libapt-inst1.4 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17) ...
Setting up libxml2 (2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.9) ...
Setting up php5-common (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Setting up php5-fpm (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...

Configuration file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** www.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
update-rc.d: warning: php5-fpm stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match LSB                                                                                         Default-Stop values (none)
Setting up php5-mysql (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Setting up php5-curl (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Setting up php5-gd (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Setting up apt-utils (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
demouser@Titan:~$ sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
demouser@Titan:~$ sudo poweroff
demouser@Titan:~$
Broadcast message from demouser@Titan
        (/dev/pts/0) at 17:20 ...

The system is going down for power off NOW!
```

These updates are related with: http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2254-1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error after updating my server and found the following error in /var/log/nginx/error.log:`/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied)`

What solved the issue was uncommenting the following lines in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and restart php5-fpm

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked like charm. Just for information. May you say why it worked? Previously there was no need to uncomment the lines.

Comment: I think something has changed in the php5-fpm install. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443398/nginx-error-connect-to-php5-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same error and I had to put in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

`user  www-data www-data`;